# What happened to my VS Team project bindings?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I'm new to using Team Explorer, I create a new project in source control using VSTS, then I see the plus signs, check marks etc.

Then I closed the project and reopened it, all the plus signs and check marks are gone as if the project is not under source control.

Why is this happening I wonder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably been disconnected.  Use the Source Code Control menu item on the File menu to reconnect to your TFS server.